# python if does not equal with beautifulsoup and urllib

Tags: python, if-statement, beautifulsoup, operators, urllib

Here is yet another problem I am over thinking. I want the code to only print when the time that I scrape changes. All it does now is just keep printing the current price and never changes. What am I doing wrong?

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs


while True:
    # Request Webpage
    url = 
urllib.request.urlopen('https://markets.businessinsider.com/index/realtime-chart/dow_jones').read()

    # Raw Webpage
    rawpage = bs.BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')

    price = rawpage.find_all('span', class_='push-data')[0]
    change = rawpage.find_all('span', class_='push-data')[1]
    currenttime = rawpage.find_all('span', class_='push-data')[3]
    new_time = ""

    if new_time != currenttime:
        print(price.text)
        print(change.text)
        print(currenttime.text)
```

Comment: you need to define some value to `new_time` and in `if` shouldn't it be `new_time != currenttime.text`?

Comment: Tried that and it still isn't working. :(

Comment: I am testing it. tell me value of `new_time`

Comment: Omit my last comment. I set an initial `new_time` value and then changed the `if new_time != currenttime:` to ` if currenttime != new_time:` and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs
import csv

#Request Webpage
url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://markets.businessinsider.com/index/realtime-chart/dow_jones').read()

# Raw Webpage

rawpage = bs.BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
new_time = rawpage.find_all('span', class_='push-data')[3]
price = rawpage.find_all('span', class_='push-data')[0]
change = rawpage.find_all('span', class_='push-data')[1]
all_data = [price.text, change.text, new_time.text]
print(all_data)
try:
    with open("dow_price.csv", "w+", newline="") as dow_writer:
        writer = csv.writer(dow_writer)
        writer.writerow(all_data)
except:
    pass


while True:
    # Request Webpage
    url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://markets.businessinsider.com/index/realtime-chart/dow_jones').read()

# Raw Webpage
rawpage = bs.BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')

price = rawpage.find_all('span', class_='push-data')[0]
change = rawpage.find_all('span', class_='push-data')[1]
currenttime = rawpage.find_all('span', class_='push-data')[3]


if currenttime != new_time:
    all_data = [price.text, change.text, currenttime.text]
    try:
        with open("dow_price.csv", "a", newline='') as dow_writer:
            writer = csv.writer(dow_writer)
            writer.writerow(all_data)
    except:
        pass
    print(all_data)
new_time = currenttime
url = ""
rawpage = ""
```